# Remove class if other class present at scroll height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide an element on scroll - but only if its not already hidden.

I've written the following `jQuery` but it's not working for some reason - any tips please?

The css class `open-style-switcher` and `close-style-switcher` determine a css scroll anim. I want to wait until the page has scrolled to a certain height, then auto hide the search box if it contains the open class.

Where am I going wrong!?

```
  $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {

        $('#search-box').hasClass('open-style-switcher').toggleClass("open-style-switcher", "close-style-switcher", 1000);

    }
});
```

Comment: `$('#search-box').hasClass('open-style-switcher')` it returns `boolean`, so you can't chain it further.

Comment: Also toggleClass does not take these arguments: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) - `Returns: Boolean` determines whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

In your scenario, `addClass` and `removeClass` is more suitable.

See below :

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var searchbox = $('#search-box');
  if (scroll >= 500 && searchbox.hasClass('open-style-switcher')) {
    searchbox.removeClass("open-style-switcher");
    searchbox.addClass("close-style-switcher", 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: DRY - you should cache `$('#search-box')` in a variable and use that instead of selecting it 3 times (2 of which could have been chained)

Answer (score 2):

"toggleClass" can receive two classes separated by space
Also creating "$searchBox" variable to avoid double search in DOM.
And as was told before: hasClass() returns boolean
Here it is:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 500) {
        var $searchBox = $('#search-box');
        if ($searchBox.hasClass('open-style-switcher'))
        {
             $searchBox.toggleClass("open-style-switcher close-style-switcher", 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`toggleClass()` does not work in the way you, or even the other answers, think it does. It only adds and removes classes, not exchange them for others. See [toggleClass() documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-function-state).

```
if (scroll >= 500) {
    if($('#search-box').hasClass('open-style-switcher'))
    {
       $('#search-box').removeClass("open-style-switcher");
       $('#search-box').addClass("close-style-switcher");
    }
}
```

I imagine you will also want an else block that does the inverse of this. Perhaps the below is a more straight forward way of doing what you want to achieve as there may not be any point in the check to see if the `#search-box` already has the `open-style-switcher` class.

```
if (scroll >= 500) {
    $('#search-box').removeClass("open-style-switcher").addClass("close-style-switcher");
}
else
{
    $('#search-box').removeClass("close-style-switcher").addClass("open-style-switcher");
}
```

Comment: By specifying 2 classes, you can indeed exchange two classes (as the other answer does) Test it: http://jsfiddle.net/erbys4Lz/ Basically, there is no need for a `removeClass` and an `addClass` you can just call `toggleClass("class1 class2")`. In fact the documentation you linked even tells you this ("className:- One or more class names (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set.")

Comment: I see the answer I was referring to has been updated. It used to state toggleClass("open-style-switcher", "close-style-switcher"); or something similar. Hence the reference to exchanging classes which this method does not do. As you point out though, it can essentially do this but I don't think it's explicit enough. For example if you end up in a situation where both classes are on the element, you're going to remove both. It's not something I use often tbh, I generally have a default ("Closed") state and an "Open" or "Active" state where I can just add or remove one class.